# Rewriting one part of a URL into a link

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get one part of a URL to insert into another.

URL in address bar will read domain.com/test.php?/12345 then link in page must become domain.com/do/Login/12345 (this end number will change for every user)

(Note that I can't change the URL domain.com/test.php?/12345 as this has already been set by the site owner.)

For the URLs above I had to remove the http://www. part above as new user can't submit more than one link for spam prevention. The final script should include http://www.

You will be able to see that all I need to get is the number at the end ie 12345 but I'm not too sure how to achieve this (javascript beginner). This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Path test</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
// get URL eg http://www.domain.com/test.php?/12345
newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
</script>

<script>
//write new domain then add user number ie 12345
document.write('http://www.domain.com/do/Login/' + window.location.pathname);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This obviously does not work but shows where I got to.

I've had some luck using a script I found at http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=244955 but it only worked with filenames with an extension name on like .html, .php etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get the part of the url after the question mark. This is available in the

```
 window.location.search
```

variable. Note that that already includes the "/". Then you need to create the actual link. document.write('http://...) won't work because that will just write it in text form and will not be an actual anchor tag. For that you need something like:

```
document.getElementById("yourLink").href = "http://domain.com/do/Login" + window.location.search
```

don't forget to put an anchor tag in the html with an id that matches the element in the getElementById() method above. If you don't want to put an anchor tag in your html markup, you can create one with javascript with something like:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "http://domain.com/do/Login" + window.location.search;
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

This may need further adjusting to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That almost does it. This may not be the best way to do it with my JS not being great but using

<script>
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "http://www.testingforschools.com/do/Login" + window.location.search;
document.body.appendChild(link);
//write link
document.write('<a href="' + link + '">Link</a>');
</script>

the only problem I now have is the final link is http://www.domain.com/do/Login?/12345. Only the question mark after /Login needs to go so it reads http://www.domain.com/do/Login/12345

Comment: Just use the substr() method on the window.location.search variable like so: window.location.search.substr(1). Oh, and try to do some research next time. You can find all the methods the various JS objects have in w3schools. The string object is here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: @Jamie - If this is the correct answer can you please mark it as so, so that in the future this will be more helpful to other users?

Comment: Thanks Devius. It works perfectly. You're right about doing more research. My only problem was I'm new to JS and wasn't sure what I was looking for. Also I've found on StackOverflow that the notifications seem to come though quite a while after a comment is made so that's why I hadn't seen your latest answer yesterday. Thanks again for your excellent answers.

Answer (score 0):

Could this do the work? It uses the whole URL, splits it from the '?' (meaning from the start of the parameters) and then concatenates the parameters to the base URL.

```
var oldUrl = window.location.href;
var parameters = oldUrl.substring(oldUrl.indexOf('?',0),oldUrl.length);

var newUrlBase = 'http://www.domain.com/do/Login/';
var newUrl = newUrlBase + parameters;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This almost works but outputs http://www.domain.com/do/Login/?/12345. Can this be adjusted to output http://www.domain.com/do/Login/12345 so ?/ is removed before 12345